# Is there a nunit-console-runner.dll for NUnit 3.0?

Tags: c#, dll, nunit-3.0

NUnit 2.6.4 had a nunit-console-runner.dll file that I could use in my C# app as follows:

```
string[] my_args = { "/run=SmokeTests.ATest", "Tests.dll" };
NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(my_args);
```

But I don't see this dll in 3.0. Is there one? If not, how can i use the same command to run NUnit tests programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Nunit 3 Console Runner can be installed as a reference of the nuget package from -  https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.ConsoleRunner/

nunit3-console.exe file will be stored under Project Directory >> Package >> nunit-console runner folder

Further documentation can be found here - https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Runner